# Linq does not return the correct result

Tags: c#, linq

I need to retrieve a percentage with a linq query but it does not work, I have tried with different stuff as follow

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

var actualTime = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

List<RelacionEjecucionPendientes> iniciativasEjecucionPendienteses = actividades
            .GroupBy(cl => cl.iniciativaName)
            .Select(cl => new RelacionEjecucionPendientes
            {
                Nombre = cl.Key,
                ATiempoEjecucionCantidad = cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) >= 0),
                ATiempoEjecucionPorcentaje =  
                    ((cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day >= 0) /
                    (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1)))
                    * 100,
                DesfazadasEjecucionCantidad = cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) < 0),
                DesfazadasEjecucionPorcentaje = String.Format("{0:0.00}",
                    ((cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && ((Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day) < 0)) /
                    (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1)))
                    * 100),
                ATiempoPendientesCantidad = cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaInicio).Day - actualTime.Day) >= 0),
                ATiempoPendientesPorcentaje =  
                    ((cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada" && ((Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaInicio) - actualTime).Days >= 0)) /
                    (cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada") : 1)))
                    * 100,
                DesfazadasPendientesCantidad = cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaInicio).Day - actualTime.Day) < 0),
                DesfazadasPendientesPorcentaje = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 
                    ((cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada" && (Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaInicio).Day - actualTime.Day) < 0) /
                    (cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado == "No Iniciada") : 1)))
                    * 100)
            }).ToList();
```

Any of this percentage work correctly

ATiempoEjecucionPorcentaje
DesfazadasEjecucionPorcentaje
ATiempoPendientesPorcentaje
DesfazadasPendientesPorcentaje

But this seems to work fine:

ATiempoEjecucionCantidad
DesfazadasEjecucionCantidad
ATiempoPendientesCantidad
DesfazadasPendientesCantidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like integer division problem. Cast one of the numbers to `double` to make it work:

```
ATiempoEjecucionPorcentaje =  
    (((double)cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada" && Convert.ToDateTime(c.fechaVencimiento).Day - actualTime.Day >= 0) /
    (cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") != 0 ? cl.Count(c => c.estado != "No Iniciada") : 1)))
    * 100,
```